# Custom grunt task to concat multiple JS files from different folders into a single JS file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I am writing custom grunt task to concat multiple JS files from different folders into a single JS file. When i run grunt command, it shows that "Running 'read-folder-concat' task. After that, nothing happens. I am unable to see any errors on the console. I am totally stuck here.

There are two files, one is Gruntfile.js & concat-task.js. I am sharing code here of these files.

```
Gruntfile.js

// Grunt configuration file
(function () {
    'use strict';

    module.exports = function (grunt) {

        grunt.initConfig({
            pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

            concat: {
                options: {
                    separator: ';'
                }
            }                        
        });

        //load grunt tasks
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
        grunt.task.loadTasks('./tasks');

        //register grunt default task
        grunt.registerTask('default', ['read-folder-concat']);

    };
})();

concat-task.js

(function () {

    'use strict';

    module.exports = function (grunt) {

        function readFolderAndConcat(pathArr) {

            // get the current concat config
            var i,
                src = [],
                concat = grunt.config.get('concat') || {};

            for (i = 0; i < pathArr.length; i++) {
                grunt.file.expand(pathArr[i]).forEach(function (dir) {
                    src.push(dir);
                });
            }

            // set the config for this modulename-directory
            concat =  {
                dist: {
                    src: [src.join(",")],
                    dest: 'app_min_safe/app/min/app.js'
                }
            };

            // save the new concat configuration
            grunt.config.set('concat', concat);

            // when finished run the concatinations
            grunt.task.run('concat');
        }

        grunt.registerTask("read-folder-concat", "read folder dynamically and concat it.", function () {

            readFolderAndConcat(["app/*.js", "app/modules/js/*/*.js"]);

        });
    };
})();
```

Please help me understand what is the issue in my concat task.

Comment: You don't need to create a separate task to achieve this, default grunt-contrib-concat can be configured to achieve this functionality.

Comment: I know, but i want to do it through separate task which can be easy to scale in future. It would be easy to add more functionality in that separate task.